# one search input multiple names

Tags: javascript, html, html-input

So I am working on a website where you have one search bar and you can search with multiple websites like google, amazon, youtube and some more. My problem is, that all this is in one form and I can't use the name="q" which is working on the most search api's on amazon and wikipedia, because there are the names k (amazon) and search (wikipedia). Does anyone know how to change the name f the input for two buttons?

Here's the link: https://multi-search.bss.design/

```html
<form target="_blank">
  <input class="form-control visible" type="search" name="q" autofocus="" autocomplete="off" id="input" placeholder="Search...">
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-circle" type="submit" value="Google" formaction="http://www.google.de/search" target="_blank" value="Google"><span><i class="fa fa-google animated" ></i></span></button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-circle" type="submit" value="YouTube" formaction="https://www.youtube.com/search" target="_blank"><span><i class="fa fa-youtube-play animated"></i></span></button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-circle" type="submit" value="Amazon" formaction="https://www.amazon.de/s/" target="_blank"><span><i class="fa fa-amazon animated"></i></span></button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-circle" type="submit" value="Google Translate" formaction="https://translate.google.com/#auto/de/" target="_blank"><span><i class="fas fa-language animated"></i></span></button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-circle" type="submit" value="Google Images" formaction="http://www.google.com/images?q"><span><i class="fa fa-image animated"></i></span></button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-circle" type="submit" value="Netflix" formaction="https://www.netflix.com/search?q"><span><i class="fa fa-film animated"></i></span></button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-circle" type="submit" value="Wikipedia" formaction="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?"><span><i class="fa fa-wikipedia-w animated"></i></span></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply store a `data-` attribute on each button representing the corresponding `name` attribute (defaulting to `q`) and change it dynamically upon click.

e.g. :
`<button ... type="submit" value="Wikipedia" data-search-input-name="search">`

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button[type="submit"]').forEach(function(submitButton) {
  submitButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    document.querySelector('[data-input-search]').setAttribute('name', 
      this.getAttribute('data-search-input-name') || 'q');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input data-input-search class="form-control visible" type="search" name="q" autofocus="" autocomplete="off" id="input" placeholder="Search...">
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-circle" type="submit" value="Google" formaction="http://www.google.de/search" target="_blank" value="Google"><span><i class="fa fa-google animated" ></i></span>Google</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-circle" type="submit" value="YouTube" formaction="https://www.youtube.com/search" target="_blank"><span><i class="fa fa-youtube-play animated"></i></span>YouTube</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-circle" type="submit" value="Amazon" formaction="https://www.amazon.de/s/" data-search-input-name="k" target="_blank"><span><i class="fa fa-amazon animated"></i></span>Amazon</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-circle" type="submit" value="Google Translate" formaction="https://translate.google.com/#auto/de/" target="_blank"><span><i class="fas fa-language animated"></i></span>Translate</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-circle" type="submit" value="Google Images" formaction="http://www.google.com/images?q"><span><i class="fa fa-image animated"></i></span>Images</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-circle" type="submit" value="Netflix" formaction="https://www.netflix.com/search?q"><span><i class="fa fa-film animated"></i></span>Netflix</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-circle" type="submit" value="Wikipedia" formaction="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?" data-search-input-name="search"><span><i class="fa fa-wikipedia-w animated"></i></span>Wikipedia</button>
</form>
```

**Note**: only Wikipedia button works here as Google/Amazon block that from an iframe, but you can test Wikipedia.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, it's working now, i was working on ths problem so long, but it's that simple, thxxxxx

Comment: If you could please take a look on https://multi-search.bss.design/ in the preview of bootstrap studio it's working but not, on the url.

Comment: The JS doesn't seem to be executed. If you paste it on your browser's console and then click the Wiki search button you'll see that it does work. Now why it's not being executed from that .js file on your website I can't say.

Comment: @Sebastian You have a `Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined` error that seems to be triggered on the same script file, before the added JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can for example:

**1.** Add hidden fields

```
<input type="search" name="q" onkeyup="updateHiddenFields()">
<input type="hidden" name="k">
```

and synchronize then using JS code:

```
const updateHiddenFields = (evt) => {
   document.getElementsByName('k')[0].value = document.getElementsByName('q') .[0].value 
};
```

**2.** Rename field when button is clicked:

```
document.getElementById('button-amazon')[0].onclick = () => document.getElementsByName('q')[0].setAttribute('name', 'k');
```

(Add `id="button-amazon"` to the Amazon button to make this working.)

Comment: thanks for ur answer, but I was to stupid to do it that way